# Bootstrap based mobile website - remove extra padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap on a website which I have used many times before. However I seem to be getting space added to the right hand side and I cannot figure out where it is coming from.

You can view the website here [hutchcreative.co.uk](http://hutchcreative.co.uk/rod/weddings/) and a good way to test for mobile on your computer is using the google extension [Mobile Tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobiletablet-device-testi/elmekokodcohlommfikpmojheggnbelo?hl=en).

My first thought was that it was likely to be the carousel, however if I go to the blog I still have the problem. It's only on mobile version (works fine on tablet) and I don't remember it always happening.

Comment: I think problem is on your footer.Your may put left or right margin thats why it came like that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the margin and use padding instead:

```
#footerlogo{
    /* margin-left:20px; */
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much :) Stupid of me not to spot that